# Adding a point to a bokeh plot on click

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I'm trying to set up a bokeh plot where the user can click on the plot to add a point. I've seen [this example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.1/docs/user_guide/interaction.html#customjs-for-tools) which uses the `BoxSelectTool` to add `Rect` glyphs to the plot, however I'm looking for a way to add circle glyphs centered at the click location. I would also like to then send these points back to the server side of things. Anyone have any experience doing something similar?

Comment: this question is very old, but i've posted the solution i found below because i was searching for something alike - in case it can help others

Answer (score 11):

This works for me in Bokeh version 0.12.13:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Column
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.events import DoubleTap

coordList=[]

TOOLS = "tap"
bound = 10
p = figure(title='Double click to leave a dot.',
           tools=TOOLS,width=700,height=700,
           x_range=(-bound, bound), y_range=(-bound, bound))

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[], y=[]))   
p.circle(source=source,x='x',y='y') 

#add a dot where the click happened
def callback(event):
    Coords=(event.x,event.y)
    coordList.append(Coords) 
    source.data = dict(x=[i[0] for i in coordList], y=[i[1] for i in coordList])        
p.on_event(DoubleTap, callback)

layout=Column(p)

curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

(to run it save this script as something.py and run in a cmd: bokeh serve something.py --show )

[image]

Comment: the reset doesn't do anything for me. bokeh server version 1.1.0

Comment: the bokeh figure reset button only resets a selection, zoom, pan,.. It does not reset your source data. If you want to reset your source data too the easiest way is to refresh your page. Otherwise you can add a button with a callback that resets your source.